# The fastest way of checking the closest distance between points

Tags: python, distance, maya, points

I have 2 dictionaries. Both have key value pairs of an index and a world space location.

Something like:

```
{
  "vertices" : 
  {
    1: "(0.004700, 130.417480, -13.546420)",
    2: "(0.1, 152.4, 13.521)",
    3: "(58.21, 998.412, -78.0051)"
  }
}
```

Dictionary 1 will always have about 20 - 100 entries, dictionary 2 will always have around 10,000 entries.

For every point in dictionary 1, I want to find the point in dictionary 2 that's closest to it. What is the fastest way of doing that? For each entry in dictionary 1, loop through **all entries** in dictionary 2 and return the one that's closest by.

Some untested pseudo code:

```
for point, distance in dict_1.iteritems():
    closest_point = get_closest_point(dict_1.get(point))


def get_closest_point(self, start_point)

    furthest_distance = 2000000
    closest_point = 0

    for index, end_point in dict_1.iteritems():
        distance = get_distance(self, start_point, end_point)
        if distance < furthest_distance:
            furthest_distance = distance
            closest_point = closest_point

    return closest_point
```

I think something like this will work. The *"problem"* is that if I have 100 entries in dictionary 1, it will be 100 x 10,000 = 1,000,000 iterations. That just doesn't seem very fast or elegant to me.

**Is there a better way of doing this in Maya/Python?**

EDIT:
Just want to comment that I've used a closestPointOnMesh node before, which works just fine and is a lot easier if the points you're checking against are actually part of a mesh. You could do something like this:

```
selected_object = pm.PyNode(pm.selected()[0])
cpom = pm.createNode("closestPointOnMesh", name="cpom")

for vertex, distance in dict_1.iteritems():
    selected_object.worldMesh >> cpom.inMesh

    cpom.inPosition.set(dict_1.get(vertex))
    print "closest vertex is %s " % cpom.closestVertexIndex.get()
```

Instant reply from the node and all is dandy. However, if the list of point you're checking against are not part of a mesh you can't use this. Would it actually be possible/quicker to:

- Construct a mesh out of the points in dictionary 2
- Use mesh with closestPointOnMesh node
- Delete mesh

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need an acceleration structure for non-trivial amounts of points.  A KD tree or an octree is what you want -- KD trees are more performant on search but slower to build and can be harder to code. Also since Octrees are spatial rather than binary they may make it easier to do trivial tests.

You can get a python octree here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498121-python-octree-implementation/

if you're doing a lot of distance checks you'll definitely want to use Maya API vector classes to do the actual math compares -- that will be much, much faster than the equivalent python although.  You can get these from `pymel.datatypes` if you don't know the API well, although using the newer API2 versions is pretty painless.

Answer (score 0):

You need what is called a KD Tree. Build a KD Tree with points in your second dictionary and query for the closest point to each point in first dictionary.

I am not familiar with maya, if you can use scipy, you can use [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

PS: There seems to be an implementation in C++ [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2008help/RefGuide/node147.html).